# Why is order of finitely generated subgroup bounded above by product of orders of elements?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated

Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_k\}$ be a subset of an abelian group $G$. Let $\langle{A}\rangle$ be a subgroup generated by $A$. Suppose that each $a_i\in A$ has finite order $d_i$. Then there are exactly $d_i$ distinct powers of $a_i$ for each $i$. Observe that each element of $\langle{A}\rangle$ is of the form $a_1^{\alpha_1}a_2^{\alpha_2}...a_n^{\alpha_n}$ with $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**Claim**: The total number of distinct products of the form $a_1^{\alpha_1}a_2^{\alpha_2}...a_n^{\alpha_n}$ is at most $d_1d_2...d_k$

That is,

$$| \langle A \rangle |\leq d_1d_2...d_k$$

**My Question**

I am confused why the order of the generated group is bounded above by the product. In what case might it be less than the product and in what case is it exactly the product of the orders of the generating elements. I am assuming that the product itself follows by a counting argument.

Thanks.

Comment: "Observe that each element of $\langle{A}\rangle$ is of the form $a_1^{\alpha_1}a_2^{\alpha_2}...a_n^{\alpha_n}$ with $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Z}$." This is false in general—it's true if $G$ is abelian, but that assumption isn't available to us.

Comment: Yes, I should edit my question. I forgot to add that assumption. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend trying some examples. One instructive example is $G=\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$; try various subsets $A$ of cardinality $2$ and see what happens.

Comment: Does it not follow from the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups? (This is not rhetorical.)

Comment: @Shaun that's like swatting flies with global thermonuclear warfare.